# DRC Laser / Stereo Disparity between Collision and Visual Elements

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It is fantastic to have DRCSIM 2.0 and Gazebo 1.4, thanks! Obviously a huge part of the DRC competition is rectifying data between stereo and laser, but these produce differing results. Robots can only interact with collision boundaries based on objects; if it can't collide it can't affect.

The disparity is that the /multisense_sl/camera/points2 data produces point clouds based on visual elements, while /multisense_sl/laser/scan produces point clouds based on collision boundaries.

Visual data is not useful if it doesn't lead to a means of interaction.

[image: Link to Laser data of collision boundaries of DRC_vehicle]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1234/drc-laser-/-stereo-disparity-between-collision-and-visual-elements/) by [klowrey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/113/klowrey/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I believe this pull-request will resolve this issue:
https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/188/missing-gpu-laser-ray-sensor-in-13-issue/diff

It will enable the use of render-based ray sensor.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ThomasK](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16/thomask/) on 2013-02-05**:
Partially ... GPU laser sensor is capped at 90 degrees as it's intended to be used for sensors with a 2d image sensor I think (e.g. TOF sensors or Kinect or other depth cameras), but you could use the GPU ray sensor to extend it to a lidar sensor, see my suggestion in my comment here: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/309/use-of-visual-model-instead-of-collision

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-02-05**:
The GPU laser sensor can render a full 360 degrees. At least the test I've seen has shown that it can.

**Comment by [ThomasK](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16/thomask/) on 2013-02-05**:
Ah it's the vertical fov that is restricted to 90 degrees, it was late already yesterday :) ... all good then I guess, great